# Is there a way to force Mail.app (6.6 1510) not to convert email addresses into hyperlinks in message body?

Tags: mail.app, email, settings

I'm a system administrator, and I daily receive reports from several mail servers which contain thousands to tens of thousands of email addresses written as plain text (logwatch, from a Postfix server) mentions.  When one of these is selected as the active message, Mail hangs for up to 30-45 seconds with the spinning beach ball cursor as it converts all those addresses and also message-ID strings to hyperlinks.  Most of the message-ID strings end in an internet domain name, so they get converted too. Sample lines:

```
 NOTICE: reconnecting in response to: err=2006, HY000, DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at (eval 130) line 172.: 12 Time(s)
 Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [299.1.15.5]:60165 [299.1.15.5] <bounce-15_HTML-1470244-15974-6128593-1502@bounce.email.hsn.com> -> <omar@companyname.net>, Message-ID: <cf2bab34-2432-4880-9499-380b434c5612@xtinp2mta4208.xt.local>, mail_id: ylXNh849KLFQ, Hits: -0.388, size: 22377, queued_as: 094A84B10002, dkim_sd=200608:email.hsn.com, 4419 ms: 1 Time(s)
```

I would like to tell Mail.app not to make hyperlinks from body text, so as to avoid this issue.  I used to be able to do this in a previous version, but after an upgrade, it has reverted to this more 'friendly' behavior.  Can I tell Mail to only display plain text and attachments?

ETA:  The command line to set the 'Preferplaintext' default seems not to work in this version, though it used to in a previous version.

Comment: how about this defaults write com.apple.mail Preferplaintext -bool TRUE

Comment: Nope.  This is how I had Mail.app setup in a previous version, and I had six months or so of plaintext bliss.  Now that setting is either deprecated or ignored.